# 11200 HTTP retrieval failure

Tags: php, xml, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

When I send an SMS to my twilio phone number I see in the logs:

> Error : 11200 HTTP retrieval failure 
>   Description: An attempt to retrieve content from https://xxx.xxx.com/extapi/twilio-php/twilio.xml.php returned the HTTP status code .

Here is the content of twilio.xml.php:

```
<?php 
    header("content-type: application/xml");
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>
<Response>
    <Sms>test</Sms>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. I dissable SSL Certificate Validation in Twilio's account settings.

Comment: Hello B.kevin 
i have disable ssl Certificate but it's not working
 ERROR : 11200 There was a failure attempting to retrieve the contents of this URL
here was a failure attempting to retrieve the contents of this URL

Comment: Hello, its not exactly the same error.  
Is the file content correct ?

Answer (score 0):

From Twilio's docs at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms

```
The <Sms> verb sends an SMS message to a phone number during a phone call.
```

Notice the words '*phone call*'.

If what you want is to get a message back when you text to your Twilio number change to

```
<Response>
    <Message>test</Message>
</Response>
```

But from your question it also looks like the url is not available. 
Check by opening your url `https://xxx.xxx.com/extapi/twilio-php/twilio.xml.php` in a browser. Eventually change https to http.

Also, in the return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` should be on the first line.

Comment: I have change the url, replace xxx.xx by test.ogust and now the file is twilio.xml and the content is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message>test</Message>
</Response>`

Comment: I don't get anything when I try to browse to your url. I suggest while testing to use a TwiML bin. https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/introducing-native-twiml-bins-powered-by-the-twilio-cloud.html

Comment: https://test.ogust.com/extapi/twilio-php/twilio.xml . I just want to get the sms and put in in my database. This is just a try to see if its works. I cant use TwiML bin for this. 
Regardless of the file i always have an rerror 11200

Comment: I just tested with your url and it works. Try to configure the same url for another phone number at Twilio if you can. I suggested the bin for testing.

Comment: Why twilio's logs are inbound request failed Error
      11200 HTTP retrieval failure 
Description
    An attempt to retrieve content from https://test.ogust.com/extapi/twilio-php/twilio.xml returned the HTTP status code 502. I can see it from my web browser and i dont get the sms response.

Comment: Its works with the bin. ill try with an other twilio number

Comment: It's documented here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200 Is your phone configuration at Twilio with http or https? Is it with POST or GET? I just configured one of my phone numbers with your url, I tried with two sms and it works.

Comment: its https with post method, is it because i'm using a service ?

Comment: That's the setting I have with my number and it works. Configure with URL not with "Messaging Service"

Comment: I change the twilio's number an it still not working

Comment: you are configuring with webhooks/twiml ?

Comment: thanks for your help but its still not wirking i dont know what to do.

Comment: If it works with the bin, you could try to host your file somewhere else. Also take a look at twimlets https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112997/discussion-between-b-kevin-and-alex-baban).